# snmp trap using disman-event mib related issue

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

```
notificationEvent ifMtu.1 IF-MIB::ifMtu.1  1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.1

monitor -I -u root -s -t -r 18 "Warn: High ipp Usage" -e ifMtu.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.1 !=
```

The above lines are in my `snmpd.conf` file which is generating a trap when the condition evaluates to false.

My issue is that I want to send "Trap Severity Levels" with it. Is it possible? If so, how? If it isn't is there any other way to send them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use -o option in addition. For example:

```
monitor -o 1.3.6.1.x -o 1.3.6.2.y -I -u root -s -t -r 18 "Warn: High ipp Usage" -e ifMtu.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.1 !=
```

where:
  1.3.6.1.x and 1.3.6.2.y are two additional varbinds added to SNMP PDU payload and defined by these OIDs.

You may also refer to: [man page of snmpd.conf](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html) do